# Asymptotic behavior of integral

Tags: integration, limits

I have the following expression:
\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{\partial U}{\partial(B/J)}\right|_{JB} = -N \sqrt{JB} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi} \frac{B/J - J/B}{\sqrt{4\sin^2k/2 + (J/B - B/J)^2}}
\end{equation}
I am looking at the asymptotic behavior as $B/J - J/B \to 0$.

To me, this seems equivalent to:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{X \to 0}\left[-N \sqrt{Y} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi} \frac{X}{\sqrt{4\sin^2k/2 + X^2}}\right] = \left[-N \sqrt{Y} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi} \frac{0}{\sqrt{4\sin^2k/2}}\right] = 0
\end{equation}

But I am doubting the results because $k=0$ is within the range of integration.

What is the appropriate way to look at the asymptotic behavior?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking how do I calculate the asymptotic behavior of the RHS in the first equation in the limit where $B/J - J/B \to 0$.

Comment: To be precise you also have to note that $$
Y = \left( {\frac{{X + \sqrt {X^2  + 4} }}{2}} \right)J^2  \to J^2 .
$$

Comment: @Gary Could you please clarify how does this relate to my limit? I am very confused. Thanks

Comment: I just wanted to point out that your $Y$ also depends on your $X$, so when you take the limit $X\to 0$, $Y$ will also change.

Comment: @Gary The partial derivative has $Y = JB$ fixed. So i think(?) it makes sense to keep it as a separate variable.

Comment: $\frac{B}{J} - \frac{J}{B} = \frac{{B^2  - J^2 }}{Y}$, so if $Y$ is fixed it means that $B\to J$, in order to have $\frac{B}{J} - \frac{J}{B} \to 0$. But then $Y=JB \to J^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} \frac{dk}{\sqrt{a^2+4 \sin ^2\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}}=\frac{4 }{\sqrt{a^2+4}}K\left(\frac{4}{a^2+4}\right)$$

Assuming $B>0$ and $J>0$, let $J=\alpha B$ with $\alpha >1$
$$\left.\frac{\partial U}{\partial(\frac BJ)}\right|_{JB}=\frac {2BN}\pi \frac{\sqrt{\alpha } \left(\alpha ^2-1\right)}{\alpha ^2+1}K\left(\frac{4 \alpha ^2}{\left(\alpha ^2+1\right)^2}\right)$$ Expanding as a series around $\alpha=1$ gives with $\color{red}{\beta=\alpha-1>0}$,
$$\color{red}{K\left(\frac{4 \alpha ^2}{\left(\alpha ^2+1\right)^2}\right)=\log \left(\frac{4}{\beta }\right)+\frac 12 \beta+\frac 14\log \left(\frac{4}{ \beta \sqrt{e}}\right)\beta^2 +\frac 14\log \left(\frac{e^{2/3}}{4}  \beta \right)\beta^3 +O(\beta^4)}\tag1$$ Expanding the whole result
$$\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{\alpha } \left(\alpha ^2-1\right)}{\alpha ^2+1}K\left(\frac{4 \alpha ^2}{\left(\alpha ^2+1\right)^2}\right)=\log \left(\frac{4}{\beta }\right)\beta +\frac{1}{2} \beta^2+\frac{1}{8}
  \log \left(\frac{\beta}{4 e}\right) \beta^3+O(\beta^4)}\tag2$$

Trying for $\beta=\frac{1}{10}$
$$\frac{21}{221} \sqrt{\frac{11}{10}} K\left(\frac{48400}{48841}\right)=0.3733434\cdots$$ while $(1)$ gives
$$7 \sqrt{\frac{11}{10}}\frac{587+36081 \log (2)+12027 \log (5)}{884000}=0.3733381\cdots$$

Trying for $\beta=\frac{1}{100}$
$$\frac{201 \sqrt{101} }{202010}K\left(\frac{408040000}{408080401}\right)=0.059963778773\cdots$$ while $(1)$ gives

$$\frac{67 \sqrt{101} (29926+24000594 \log (2)+12000297 \log (5))}{404020000000}=0.059963778670\cdots$$

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in your first statement. Shouldn't it be: $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\text{d}k}{\sqrt{a^2+4\sin^2\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}} = \frac{4}{|a|}K\left(-\frac{4}{a^2}\right)$?

Comment: @user17004502. I am using Mathematica notation for elliptice integrals.

Answer (score 0):

We have as an inequality that

$$\frac{|X|}{\sqrt{4\sin^2\frac{k}{2}+X^2}}\leq \frac{|X|}{\sqrt{0+X^2}} = 1$$

Therefore your limit is justified by dominated convergence.